# Search Results Using Faceted Navigation

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, search

We sell specialized trucks and heavy equipment. Our website uses faceted navigation for users to narrow their search and find specific equipment.
We are trying to get google to show search results of our equipment.

For example, if someone searched google for "2018 Acura MDX", the serp will show several related results including autotrader, cars.com, carfax, cargurus, etc...
The user can click on any of these results and will be taken to a related page showing 2018 Acura MDX cars.

We have great content, headlines, alt tags and so on for all of our static pages. These pages rank well for google searches. Our on page SEO is doing well.

But, what should we do to our website so it is ready for users on google that search for trucks and equipment we offer, such as a year make and model?
This might be a little more complex since faceted navigation is being used, just like the big name websites like autotrader and so on.
We are not sure what needs to be done SEO wise for our product equipment to show up in google searches.